# How to edit or move text in Pinta AFTER it has been created?

Tags: pinta

I am using Pinta 1.7 on Ubuntu 20.10.

When I create text and complete it I can no longer edit the text I have created or move it around. If I try to edit it it simply writes the new text on top of the existing text.

So how to I edit existing text I have created or move it to another location?

This:

https://www.pinta-project.com/user-guide/text/

does not cover this use case.